# My Navigation bar not working properly in mobile view

Tags: html, css, nav, navigationbar

Hey my navigation bar is not working properly in mobile view
It is supposed to hide it and also show the empty area first and then when the menu is clicked its supposed to show the things which the code says but its not showing the empty area(the blank website page) first and when menu clicked its also not hiding it

The Code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700%display=swap');
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
nav{
    height: 80px;
    background: #1b1b1b;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0px 50px 0px 100px;;
}
nav .logo{
    font-size: 33px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 600;
}
nav ul{
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}
nav ul li{
    margin: 0 5px;
}
nav ul li a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a.active{
    color: #1b1b1b;
    background: #fff;
}
nav .menu-btn i{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;    
}
@media (max-width: 940px) {
    nav .menu-btn i{
        display: block;
    }
    nav ul{
        position: fixed;
        top: 80px;
        left: 0;
        background: #111;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #click:checked ~ ul{
        left: 0%;
    }
    nav ul li{
        margin: 40px 0;
    }
    nav ul li a{
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    nav ul li a:hover,
    nav ul li a.active{
        color: cyan;
        background: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <div class="logo">Brand</div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="click">
            <label for="click" class="menu-btn">
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </label>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

So yea how should i fix this
Thanks in advance

Comment: What "empty area" are you talking about? And how did you expect this to work and toggle the menu, when all you are doing based on that the checkbox was checked, is set `left: 0%` for the menu - which had `left: 0` already to begin with? _"and when menu clicked its also not hiding it"_ - nothing whatsoever in your code that could achieve that either. Clicking anything inside the menu, will not un-check the checkbox again.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

bro you did a mistake on #click:checked this part if you want select the input tag who checked you should do that from this way input[type=checkbox]

Comment: That makes no sense, the checkbox element _has_ the ID `click`, so `#click:checked` will work perfectly fine as selector for this specific element in its checked state.